# How can I install Ubuntu server on a USB stick?

Tags: server, system-installation, usb

What do I need to install a Ubuntu Server on a USB stick? I don't want to create a bootable stick, but really install the system there.

Comment: You don't really need anything other then the USB stick to install to and the installation media (CD/USB).

Comment: @mikewhatever: and just install on it as it would be a HDD?

Comment: Yep. For the installer, a USB stick looks no different then an HDD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: [LinuxLive USB](http://www.linuxliveusb.com) will do an awesome job for that.

You can make a LiveUSB from any distribution of Ubuntu (Server/Desktop). You can look on Ubuntu's Wiki, there is a step-by-step solution : [LiveUSB](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent).

I also found an article to literally install a portable Ubuntu on your flash drive : [How To: Install Portable Linux Ubuntu on a bootable USB Flash Drive](https://web.archive.org/web/20140418010815/http://mintarticles.com/read/operating-systems-articles/how-to-install-portable-linux-ubuntu-on-a-bootable-usb-flash-drive-from-sun-virtualbox,13641/).

With those two tutorials, you should be able to do what you want.

Comment: I want the second on I think, lets see what happens... thanks!

Comment: Ok, let me know if it worked ;)

Comment: Second link is broken.

Comment: Change it to LinuxLive USB, more recent.

Comment: LinuxLive USB Creator won't install Ubuntu on the USB driver, but just burn the ISO and make it bootable. It allows to run Ubuntu in live-mode, but not install the system on the USB drive

Comment: You can setup a persistance mode in LiLi so you'll have the same result.